# Tuples in a where clause

Tags: postgresql, tuples, where-clause

I have the following tables

**Table 1**

| Project | Currency | Amount1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | USD | 100 |
| P1 | EUR | 1500 |
| P2 | EUR | 300 |

**Table 2**

| Project | Currency | Amount2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | USD | 200 |
| P2 | EUR | 350 |

From these tables above , i want to be able to select Amounts from Table 1 but only for couples (Project , Currency) that exist in table 2 . So the **result** would be :

| Project | Currency | Amount2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | USD | 100 |
| P2 | EUR | 300 |

I already know how to achieve this using a left join :

```
SELECT T2.Project
    ,T2.Currency
    ,T1.Amount
FROM Table2 T2
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 T1 
    ON T1.Project = T2.Project
    AND T1.Currency = T2.Currency
```

But i wonder if it's possible to put a where clause condition on a tuple , and having a query like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM T1 
WHERE (Project,Currency) IN (SELECT DISTINCT ( Project,Currency) From Table1 )
```

For now running this query gives me table 1 as a result .

Thank's in advance for your help !

Comment: no since you need data from both tables , you need to join them

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. But your subquery is wrong as it only has a single column, not two. Those parentheses create a single column which is an anonymous record type. Additionally the `DISTINCT` is useless in a query used for an IN condition. Given your problem description you also want to select from table **2**, not table1

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_1
WHERE (Project,Currency) IN (SELECT Project,Currency 
                             From Table_2)
```